# Pandas DataReader is no longer working with the Yahoo Finance API?

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I guess this issue just arose recently. On my regular PC I have an older version of `pandas_datareader` which works fine, but on my instance I had to install the newer version and it doesn't work. It has the following error-

`Yahoo Daily has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the
introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data
connectors are welcome.`

Can I install an earlier version somehow? How do I get around this using code like the following?

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime

co = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=10), datetime.date.today())

print co.head()
```

Comment: [This was announced on their website.](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to the PyPi of pandas_datareader, download the tar.gz file (`wget <url to tar.gz file for 0.5.0>`) and type `pip install blahblah.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this [package](https://github.com/alisiddiq/py_yahoo_prices) to read from the new api https://query1.finance.yahoo.com

```
from datetime import datetime
import py_yahoo_prices.price_fetcher as pf


st_dt = datetime(2017, 6, 1)
comp_codes = ["IMM.L", "AAPL", "TSLA", ....]

# get the raw prices from yahoo, auto retries on a 401 error
raw_prices = pf.multi_price_fetch(code=comp_codes, start_date=st_dt)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.